# Do I HAVE TO create a boot disc?

Tags: boot, system-installation

Do I really have to create a boot disc? I downloaded Ubuntu. unpacked the 7zip file and installed.
Then it said I must restart for the installation to complete.
When I restarted it showed an error.
Is this because I didn't create a boot disc? I'm not technical but I would really like to use Ubuntu for safety. I'm finding it very hard to create a boot disc. I guess I'm too stupid. I don't know how to change the boot area.
Can't one just install and let it run?

Comment: Ubuntu isn't like a regular software that you can install on Windows and let it run. It's an operating system, hence has to live somewhere on a disk. Use virtual box if you want to avoid that

Comment: "unpacked the 7zip file" sorry, a what?! Where did you get this from? Ubuntu comes in .ISO format and .ISO only. Doubt any other download.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of ubuntu being available as a 7-zip file. Where did you find this download (it may be malicious).
You should download from ubuntu.com and the file type should be ISO. You will need to burn this ISO to a DVD or use unetbootin or similar to put it onto a bootable USB device.
Boot from either the DVD or ISO and you will be presented with an option to install Ubuntu. After Ubuntu is installed you won't need to boot from the DVD/USB anymore.

Comment: Oh dear. I don't think I'm able to do this. I'll have to find someone to help me. Thanks for the help. I dont' know now where I got the download. I went to Ubuntu and followed the money and then downloaded it there. Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Download VirtualBox and run the ISO file you get from Ubuntu.com with it.

- https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop